# Context-free grammars and priority

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

This grammar is supposed to give priority to multiplication:

- E -> E + T | T.
- T -> T * F | F.
- F -> x.

A derivation for "x + x * x" would be (unless I'm wrong):

E => E + T => T + T => F + T => x + T => x + T * F => x + F * F => x + x * F => x + x * x.

So how is multiplication given priority over addition? It appears that the addition is produced first.

Comment: Is this a *formal* grammar or one fed into a parser generator? Which parsing automaton/algorithm is used?

Comment: It's a formal language, I did this derivation by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that additions operator is produced first when you
derive. But when you parse, you do the opposite (reduction), and the
multiplications are recognized first, wich is precisely what you want.

THis need a bit of discussion, when you compare top-down and bottom up
parsing, but basically the bottom of the tree must be know correct
before the top can be.

More to the point, this is a consequence of the fact that the parse
tree produced with such a grammar will be structured to conform the
operator operand structure defined by priorities, up to idosyncrasies
of a CF grammar definition, which are ironed out in an abstract syntax
tree (AST). In other words, this gives the parse tree a shape that is close
to the shape desired for the AST (Thanks to Raphael for suggesting
comparison with the AST).

This is why such a grammatical definition is simpler to use to
generate the AST. More importantly, it was much more convenient in
older compilers and interpreters that did not use AST, as the parse
tree reflected the priority structure.

For example, the parse tree for `x + x * x` is

```
   E
 / | \
E  +   T
|     /|\
T    T * F
|    |   |
F    F   x
|    |
x    x
```

And the AST for `x + x * x` is

```
   +
 /   \
x     *
     / \
    x   x
```

It is derivable from the parse tree by moving all operators up one
edge on the preceding node, and then ignoring all non-terminals,
making each linear downward path a single edge. Essentially the same
shape.

This AST is the expression tree defined by the priorities, from which the meaning of the expression can be derived (by homomorphism), from which it can be evaluated or compiled.

Comment: Is the direction of parsing relevant? The tree that is obtained determines the syntax in this case, and the tree is *evaluated* bottom-up.

Comment: @HendrikJan Yes, see previous comment. The parsing direction does not matter, and that is true even without building a parse tree, though it is always implicitly there.

Comment: It's now all very clear, thanks babou (and also Raphael)!

Answer (score -3):

I think this is the case of ambiguous grammar.In the rules' list addition is definitely above multiplication and that needs to be rectified,multiplication should go above addition.

Comment: The order of the rules is merely a choice of presentation and makes no formal difference to the grammar.

Comment: @DavidRicherby care to give a reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Formal_definitions

Comment: @user4275686 One way to read the rules of a context free grammar is as a set of equations where
non-terminals are variables, terminals are constants, and these
variables take their value in the set of languages over the given
alphabet. As the name indicates, a set of equation is just a set, and
need not be ordered. That is always true, afaik, of sets of equations, BTW, the language defined is the smallest solution for the variable corresponding to the initial symbol.